# They seem to be close to each another. - is it right here?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is a picture of a family. There is a group of 4 people talking to one another pleasantly. In this situation, can I say like this?

> 1. They seem to be close to one another.
> 2. They seem to be close all together.
> 3. They seem to be close to each another.

I think #1 and 2 are good, but #3 is not right grammatically because there are more than 2.  Am I right?

Comment: "each another" is never correct, no matter how many people there are. It's simply not said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number 1 is good. It implies that they are not only in physical proximity, but also "close" emotionally.

Number 2 is not right, because we do not say "close all together". If you mean simply that they are grouped tightly in the photo, say:

- [in the photo] they are *all close together.*

You are correct that number 3 is wrong, but it is not because there are more than two in the photo. We simply do not say "each another".

Replace it, either with "one another" or with "each other".

- They seem to be close to {each other/ one another}.

Answer (score 1):

The correct would be

> They seem to be close to one another.

or

> They seem to be close to each other.

To me personally, *each other* sounds better. [Here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/each-other-versus-one-another?page=1) is more about the distinction.